# What is the documentation software that automatically creates Amazon PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I really like the design of the auto-generated documentation website for Amazon's PHP SDK. See here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/

Do they use an open-source tool that I could use to create documentation for my own code? Something like phpdocs?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not talking about source code. I'm talking about the auto-generated doc files that were created. What software did they use to create it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They appear to use [Vanity](http://www.vanitydoc.org/).

Comment: Not only appear, the developer of Vanity created it while working @ amazon when working on Vanity. [Check the readme](https://github.com/skyzyx/vanity/blob/master/README.md) ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks the same as [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1_ruby-v1.9.2/). You can browse the source code on [github](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/blob/master/lib/rdoc/generator/template/sdoc/resources/css/github.css).

Comment: Yes, some of the UI code comes from SDoc — specifically the class browser. Almost all of the rest of the code is new, though.

Comment: @RyanParman thanks for creating this excellent docs software! i've been playing around with the source and the config yml file. Are there any instructions for how to use it (i.e. i want to create some documentation for some of my php code)?